# How to profile power consumption on Nvidia Shield Tablet K1

Tags: android, profiling, nvidia

I build an Android Application on my Nvidia Shield Tablet.

Now I want profile my application, not only to improve the performance but specially to analyze the power consumption.
I saw this [link](https://codingadventures.me/2015/09/19/profiling-cuda-on-tegra-k1-shield-tablet/), but I really don't like this suggestion because is necessary root the device.
I installed Nvidia Gameworks and AndroidStudio to develop the application and my OS is Ubuntu 14.04.
I'm not expert about how to use profiling tools given by GameWorks so I would ask someone how to proceed to profile my application and investigate about power consumption.
I have not found easy and useful tutorials on the net so far

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried [Trepn Profiler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quicinc.trepn), but for some reason it's not profiling the apps as it should on my Shield as it does on other devices. That said, it could be some weird setting on my devices, as overlay applications don't work well on my device in general. Thus, give it a try and see if the app works on your tablet. It does the best job for app power profiling on other Android devices, to my experience.